# Como fazer um loop com input select PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho um array com nome de $c que fiz através de um explode preciso fazer a contagem com o for para ver se é selected. O problema está que ele faz o echo do option 2 ou quantas vezes houverem registros. Alguém tem alguma solução para isto?

```
foreach($interesse_compra as $ic)
{
   $c = explode(";",$ic->cidade);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($c);$i++)
{
   foreach($cidades as $cidade)
   {
      $select = $cidade->f_cidade == $c[$i] ?  "selected" : "";
      echo "<option value='".$cidade->f_cidade."'$select>".$cidade->f_cidade."</option>";
   }

}
```

Comment: pq `$c = explode(";",$ic->cidade);` fica dentro do foreach? dessa forma o `count()` só sera feita no último elemento de `$interesse_compra`.

Comment: É um select de múltipla seleção? Ou seja, pode ter várias opções selecionadas?

Comment: o foreach está ali pq eu uso codeigniter. Mas esta parte está normal. $c está se dividindo em 3 partes. Ai faco a contagem. Só que na contagem ele está duplicando o meus options claro e obvio pq está refazendo o mesmo processo baseado no $C[$i]. Entendeu @rray?

Comment: Sim é um select de multiplas escolhas... estou trazendo os dados do banco na parte de ediçao e preciso saber os que foram selecionados. Só que eles estão salvos separados por pono e virgula. @KaduAmaral

Comment: Por que o `explode` está dentro de um foreach? Se é um loop, todo esse código não deveria estar dentro dele também?

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta o conteúdo de `$interesse_compra` e `$cidades`? Pode imprimi-los com `var_dump($interesse_compra)` e colocar a saída na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz uma versão simplificado do seu código, parti do ponto que `$c` contém todas as cidades disponíveis e que `$cidades` possui os itens a serem selecionados.

É feita um comparação se com `in_array()` se valor atual(`$cidade`) existe em `$c` caso possitivo `$select` recebe selected, caso contrario recebe uma stringa vazia.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<select multiple size="8">
<?php
    $c = ['Rio Branco', 'Maceió','Macapá','Manaus','Salvador','Fortaleza','Brasília','Vitória','Goiânia', 'Curitiba'];
    $cidades = ['São Luís','Salvador','Cuiabá','Curitiba','Campo Grande','Belém','Maceió','Belo Horizonte'];

    foreach($cidades as $cidade){
        $select = in_array($cidade, $c)  ? $select = 'selected="selected"' : "";
        printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>'. PHP_EOL , $cidade, $select, $cidade);
    }
?>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Exemplo - phpfiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vvh1-d184)

Answer (score 2):

Pela descrição do problema, você precisa verificar se a cidade selecionada pertence a sua lista de cidades.

Para isso utilize as funções [array_map()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) e [in_array()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php):

```
$interesse = 'Recife;Campinas;Alagoas';
$cidades = ['Rio de Janeiro', 'São Paulo', 'Salvador', 'Piracicaba', 'Belo Horizonte', 'Recife'];

$interesse_array = explode(';', $interesse);

array_map(function($c) use ($cidades) {
    $selecionado = in_array($c, $cidades) ? "selected" : "false";
    echo "<option value='$c' selected='$selecionado'>$c</option>\n";
}, $interesse_array);
```

Saída:

```
<option value='Recife' selected='selected'>Recife</option>
<option value='Campinas' selected='false'>Campinas</option>
<option value='Alagoas' selected='false'>Alagoas</option>
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/TTXJLL).